# Close question when answer is not possible

Tags: discussion, questions

I have asked a question that has no possible answer due to a flaw in the underlying system that hasn't been resolved and won't get resolved. That flaw isn't completely analyzed and won't be in the future, so the given answers, though all might have helped, weren't the solution to the specific problem. I can't answer my own question as the problem hasn't been solved and won't be solved. How can I close that question (to have that question not killing my acceptance rate)?

Comment: I'd say the answer is that the problem is unsolvable for X reason. Share your research so the next person with that problem doesn't waste their time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. You can answer your own question to state what you have discovered via your research. If the question is unsolvable, the *answer* is that it is unsolvable. Post the appropriate documentation that has led you to this conclusion.
2. Forget your accept rate. It's less important than finding the right solution. If the right solution never arrives despite other people's best intentions and your own followup, then it simply never arrives. Do not feel obligated to accept an imperfect or incorrect answer just because somebody nags you over some metric.

Comment: I object strongly to #2: If it is literally impossible then the accepted answer should lay out why that is the case. Don't let future users suffer because you know something is impossible, show them via an accepted answer and your research.

Comment: @BenBrocka, strongly agree to #1 then. #2 is a related offshoot inspired by his comment about his acceptance rate and recent comments I have seen added to questions on Stack Overflow where the comment *literally* said "nothing works below but accepted an answer to keep my accept rate high." I obviously want him to provide his own answer when he finds out what it is, even if that answer is "no soup for you." I do not want him feeling pressured to accept *the wrong thing* just to keep some stupid metric at some meaningless level. Make sense?

Comment: Answered my own question, providing one more fact we found on the way, just before it was decided to workaround the issue with the provided hint until the next hardware version is out.